# How can I use .htaccess to redirect a sub domain to a specific file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

When users go to my sub domain, I want them to be redirected to a specific file I have in my subdomain. Or, to be exact, when someone goes here

> http://app.example.com/

they should be redirected to here:

> http://app.example.com/dashboard/

Everything I have tried doesn't seem to be working and the examples I have found online either don't work or don't do what I need them to do.

I'm also trying to get this to work from my root directory (from public_html). This is my file structue:

```
/ public_html
    / .htaccess
    / index.php
    / app.example.com
        / dashboard.php
```

You can see my htaccess file sitting on the top level. This is where I need to keep it.

This is my current file (including my attempt at the redirect):

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Stops people from being able to see htaccess file

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Options

Options All -Indexes +MultiViews

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Redirect app.example.com to /dashboard

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.example.com
RewriteRule ^$ /dashboard [L,R=301]

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Makes it so url can have slash at the end instead of .php extension

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Adds wwww to url if it doesnt already have it

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Try placing your redirect rule in `app.example.com/.htaccess`

Comment: @anubhava yeah that works but I don't want to do that...is there a way I can get around that?

Comment: If `DocumentRoot` for `app` subdomain is set to `app.example.com` in your Apache config then rule cannot be placed outside that path.